# What is the best way to increase slowly object movement speed and slow down the object near the end?

Tags: unity, c#

There a Lerp but also SmoothDamp.

In this script I'm using SmoothDamp but why not using Lerp ? And how should I use this script with the SmoothDamp tp make slowly increasing speed at the start ? Now it's only slow down at the end but I want it also to increase slowly at the start and then slowly down near the end.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementSpeedController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
    public float smoothTime = 0.3F;


    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, target.position, ref velocity, smoothTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the target is not moving, you can use an easing library, such as https://gist.github.com/cjddmut/d789b9eb78216998e95c . If the target is moving, you need to write a little bit of logic for acceleration and deceleration.

Comment: Try adding Time.deltaTime at the end

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function to get smooth acceleration/deceleration while moving to the target value/position:

```
float SmoothTowards(float current, float target, ref float velocity, float accel, float maxVelocity = float.PositiveInfinity)
{
    // The calculations need to be made in positive absolute values,
    // This sing variable is for the case of moving backwards (like from 10 to -5)
    // In the end we'll use this to set values to the original change direction sign:
    int sign = (target - current) > 0 ? 1 : -1;

    float distance = target - current;
    
    // Make the values positive.
    if (velocity < 0) velocity = -velocity;
    if (distance < 0) distance = -distance;

    // d: the distance that is required to decelerate over time and to stop at the target value
    //  with the given aceleration/deceleration and current velocity values:
    float t = velocity / accel;
    float d = velocity * t * 0.5f;
    // remove '* 0.5f' to get the slower deceleration effect. Velocity deceleration will be started earlier and will be slower.

    if (distance <= d)
        velocity -= accel;
    else if (distance - velocity - accel > d)
        velocity += accel;
        
    // Clamp the velocity if needed
    if (velocity > maxVelocity)
        velocity = maxVelocity;
        
    // Set the result to the original change direction sign:
    velocity *= sign;

    // Prevent overshooting:
    if (IsThresholdCrossed(current, current + velocity, target))
        return target;
    else
        return current + velocity;
}
```

The 'accel' argument is an acceleration/deceleration step. On every call the result will be increased or decreased by this value depending on the 'distance' to the target value.
The `IsThresholdCrossed(...)` function simply checks if the 'target' value is on the other side of the threshold than 'current' value:

```
bool IsThresholdCrossed(float a, float b, float threshold)
{
    if (a < threshold && threshold <= b ||
        b <= threshold && threshold < a)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

How to use it:

```
float velocityX, velocityY, velocityZ;
float acceleration = 1f;
float maxVelocity = 10f;

void Update()
{
    // First of all, let's get frame rate independent values for acceleration and maxVelocity depending in the last frame time:
    
    // with acceleration =1 the speed will be gradually increased by 1 m/s every second (or decreased while getting closer to the target)
    float accelDelta = acceleration * Time.deltaTime;
    
    // limit max speed for current frame
    float maxVelDelta = maxVelocity * Time.deltaTime;
    
    // Finally, move the transform towards the target:
    transform.position = new Vector3(
        SmoothTowards(transform.position.x, target.position.x, ref velocityX, accelDelta, maxVelDelta),
        SmoothTowards(transform.position.y, target.position.y, ref velocityY, accelDelta, maxVelDelta),
        SmoothTowards(transform.position.z, target.position.z, ref velocityZ, accelDelta, maxVelDelta)
    );
}
```